# Use jQuery in Intellij

Tags: javascript, jquery, intellij-idea

I am new in web development and Intellij Idea. I have written a simple jQuery code in HTML file and added Google CDN inside a script tag to run a jQuery code but when I try to run, it doesn't run jQuery. I have a tried lot of things but I don't get it. Please give me some ideas.

Comment: Make sure jquery is really included. Check your network console for errors or type '$' into the console and see if it returns something -- should return a function. Make sure you're executing your code when the document is ready by enclosing your code in a ```$(document).ready(funtion() {})``` block

Comment: oh and it always helps to post some sample code.

Comment: I have written this code but its not working $(document).ready(function(){
        alert("hi");
        })

Comment: any console errors? Did you see if jQuery was really included?

Comment: ya its not included and i dont know how to include in intellij.

Comment: Please do post your code. There is nothing IntelliJ-specific about including JQuery in a Web page; it's done in exactly the same way as in Notepad.